# What template system could I use to generate text fragments for all combination of input arrays?

Tags: jinja2, mustache

I have a 'template' that I wish to use to create potentially millions of text fragment, lets say this

```
Fragment {{loop1}}_{{loop2}}
```

Now, I define that the `loop1` is from `1` to `3` and `loop2` is from `A` to `C`. I want a template system to generate:

```
Fragment 1_A
Fragment 1_B
Fragment 1_C
Fragment 2_A
Fragment 2_B
...
Fragment 3_C
```

What should I use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

with jinja2 you could play with something like this:

```
{% set loop1 = [1,2,3] %}
{% set loop2 = [A,B,C] %}
{% for i1 in loop1 %}
{% for i2 in loop2 %}
Fragment {{i1}}_{{i2}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```